# Installing CitrixReceiver.exe without any user prompts

Tags: powershell, windows-10, citrix

I'm trying to install CitrixReceiver.exe silently via a PowerShell v5 script so the user doesn't get prompted for anything.

```
Start-Process "C:\HelpDesk\CitrixReceiver.exe" -ArgumentList '/silent' -wait
```

The script this is in is always ran with administrator privileges. But, there is a windows security prompt that appears with the options of "run" and "cancel". I am running windows 10 enterprise, so when I go to the .exe file and go to it's properties, there is no option to "unblock" the file like stated in another similar question I found. I've also tried using the /quiet and /qb arguments but the prompt still appears. How can I get this security prompt to stop appearing?

Comment: Did you try `-Verb Runas` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in an administrator command prompt:

```
C:\HelpDesk\CitrixReceiver.exe /q:a /c:"install /q"
```

I'm not sure if this will work in powershell, but it worked in a regular prompt for a different executable that I had to install quietly earlier today. You could always save it in a batch file and then call it from powershell if it doesn't work directly in powershell.

More info on these switches and quietly installing an exe file can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994349.aspx).

Comment: Ended up calling a batch file in order to install it. Thanks! My apologies for the late feedback.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help. I was working with the same issue and figured I'd see if I could answer an SO question or two.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix Receiver supports the "/silent" switch however you need to specify other parameters as well.  One example is:

```
C:\HelpDesk\CitrixReceiver.exe ENABLEPRELAUNCH=TRUE ALLOWADDSTORE=S ENABLE_SSON=YES ALLOWSAVEPWD=A UseCategoryAsStartMenuPath=True /STORE0="PNAgent;https://testserver.net/Citrix/PNAgent/config.xml;on;My PNAgent Site" /silent /includeSSON /noreboot
```

All the installation switches and instructions are avaible at Citrix' site: 
http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/windows/4-3/receiver-windows-install-wrapper/receiver-windows-cfg-command-line-42.html

However uses will still have to login the first time they launch the application, and if no store is specified they'll also have to input the store url.

Comment: Rereading your question, it seems you may be talking about trying to bypass the windows User Access Control.   Try disabling that first and see that's what's causing the issue.   If i'm on the wrong track, is it possible to add a picture?